# Python multiprocessing - AssertionError: can only join a child process

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, python-multiprocessing

I'm taking my first foray into the python mutliprocessing module and I'm running into some problems. I'm very familiar with the threading module but I need to make sure the processes I'm executing are running in parallel.

Here's an outline of what I'm trying to do. Please ignore things like undeclared variables/functions because I can't paste my code in full.

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def wrap_func_to_run(host, args, output):
    output.append(do_something(host, args))
    return

def func_to_run(host, args):
    return do_something(host, args)

def do_work(server, client, server_args, client_args):
    server_output = func_to_run(server, server_args)
    client_output = func_to_run(client, client_args)
    #handle this output and return a result
    return result

def run_server_client(server, client, server_args, client_args, server_output, client_output):
    server_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=wrap_func_to_run, args=(server, server_args, server_output))
    server_process.start()  
    client_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=wrap_func_to_run, args=(client, client_args, client_output))
    client_process.start()
    server_process.join()
    client_process.join()
    #handle the output and return some result    

def run_in_parallel(server, client):
    #set up commands for first process
    server_output = client_output = []
    server_cmd = "cmd"
    client_cmd = "cmd"
    process_one = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_server_client, args=(server, client, server_cmd, client_cmd, server_output, client_output))
    process_one.start()
    #set up second process to run - but this one can run here
    result = do_work(server, client, "some server args", "some client args")
    process_one.join()
    #use outputs above and the result to determine result
    return final_result

def main():
    #grab client
    client = client()
    #grab server
    server = server()
    return run_in_parallel(server, client)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 319, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 143, in join
    assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only join a child process'
AssertionError: can only join a child process
```

I've tried a lot of different things to fix this but my feeling is that there's something wrong with the way I'm using this module.

EDIT:

So I created a file that will reproduce this by simulating the client/server and the work they do - Also I missed an important point which was that I was running this in unix. Another important bit of information was that `do_work` in my actual case involves using `os.fork()`. I was unable to reproduce the error without also using `os.fork()` so I'm assuming the problem is there. In my real world case, that part of the code was not mine so I was treating it like a black box (likely a mistake on my part). Anyways here's the code to reproduce -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import multiprocessing
import time
import os
import signal
import sys

class Host():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "host"

    def work(self):
        #override - use to simulate work
        pass

class Server(Host):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "server"

    def work(self):
        x = 0
        for i in range(10000):
            x+=1
        print x
        time.sleep(1)

class Client(Host):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "client"

    def work(self):
        x = 0
        for i in range(5000):
            x+=1
        print x
        time.sleep(1)

def func_to_run(host, args):
    print host.name + " is working"
    host.work()
    print host.name + ": " + args
    return "done"

def do_work(server, client, server_args, client_args):
    print "in do_work"
    server_output = client_output = ""
    child_pid = os.fork()
    if child_pid == 0:
        server_output = func_to_run(server, server_args)
        sys.exit(server_output)
    time.sleep(1)

    client_output = func_to_run(client, client_args)
    # kill and wait for server to finish
    os.kill(child_pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    (pid, status) = os.waitpid(child_pid, 0)

    return (server_output == "done" and client_output =="done")

def run_server_client(server, client, server_args, client_args):
    server_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func_to_run, args=(server, server_args))
    print "Starting server process"
    server_process.start()
    client_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func_to_run, args=(client, client_args))
    print "Starting client process"
    client_process.start()
    print "joining processes"
    server_process.join()
    client_process.join()
    print "processes joined and done"

def run_in_parallel(server, client):
    #set up commands for first process
    server_cmd = "server command for run_server_client"
    client_cmd = "client command for run_server_client"
    process_one = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_server_client, args=(server, client, server_cmd, client_cmd))
    print "Starting process one"
    process_one.start()
    #set up second process to run - but this one can run here
    print "About to do work"
    result = do_work(server, client, "server args from do work", "client args from do work")
    print "Joining process one"
    process_one.join()
    #use outputs above and the result to determine result
    print "Process one has joined"
    return result

def main():
    #grab client
    client = Client()
    #grab server
    server = Server()
    return run_in_parallel(server, client)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I remove the use of `os.fork()` in `do_work` I don't get the error and the code behaves like I would have expected it before (except for the passing of outputs which I've accepted as my mistake/misunderstanding). I can change the old code to not use os.fork() but I'd also like to know why this caused this problem and if there's a workable solution.

EDIT 2:

I started working on a solution that omits os.fork() before the accepted answer. Here's what I have with some tweaking to the amount of simulated work that can be done -

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import multiprocessing
import time
import os
import signal
import sys
from Queue import Empty

class Host():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "host"

    def work(self, w):
        #override - use to simulate work
        pass

class Server(Host):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "server"

    def work(self, w):
        x = 0
        for i in range(w):
            x+=1
        print x
        time.sleep(1)

class Client(Host):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "client"

    def work(self, w):
        x = 0
        for i in range(w):
            x+=1
        print x
        time.sleep(1)

def func_to_run(host, args, w, q):
    print host.name + " is working"
    host.work(w)
    print host.name + ": " + args
    q.put("ZERO")
    return "done"

def handle_queue(queue):
    done = False
    results = []
    return_val = 0
    while not done:
        #try to grab item from Queue
        tr = None
        try:
            tr = queue.get_nowait()
            print "found element in queue"
            print tr
        except Empty:
            done = True
        if tr is not None:
            results.append(tr)
    for el in results:
        if el != "ZERO":
            return_val = 1
    return return_val

def do_work(server, client, server_args, client_args):
    print "in do_work"
    server_output = client_output = ""
    child_pid = os.fork()
    if child_pid == 0:
        server_output = func_to_run(server, server_args)
        sys.exit(server_output)
    time.sleep(1)

    client_output = func_to_run(client, client_args)
    # kill and wait for server to finish
    os.kill(child_pid, signal.SIGTERM)
    (pid, status) = os.waitpid(child_pid, 0)

    return (server_output == "done" and client_output =="done")



def run_server_client(server, client, server_args, client_args, w, mq):
    local_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    server_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func_to_run, args=(server, server_args, w, local_queue))
    print "Starting server process"
    server_process.start()
    client_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=func_to_run, args=(client, client_args, w, local_queue))
    print "Starting client process"
    client_process.start()
    print "joining processes"
    server_process.join()
    client_process.join()
    print "processes joined and done"
    if handle_queue(local_queue) == 0:
        mq.put("ZERO")

def run_in_parallel(server, client):
    #set up commands for first process
    master_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    server_cmd = "server command for run_server_client"
    client_cmd = "client command for run_server_client"
    process_one = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_server_client, args=(server, client, server_cmd, client_cmd, 400000000, master_queue))
    print "Starting process one"
    process_one.start()
    #set up second process to run - but this one can run here
    print "About to do work"
    #result = do_work(server, client, "server args from do work", "client args from do work")
    run_server_client(server, client, "server args from do work", "client args from do work", 5000, master_queue)
    print "Joining process one"
    process_one.join()
    #use outputs above and the result to determine result
    print "Process one has joined"
    return_val = handle_queue(master_queue)
    print return_val
    return return_val

def main():
    #grab client
    client = Client()
    #grab server
    server = Server()
    val = run_in_parallel(server, client)
    if val:
        print "failed"
    else:
        print "passed"
    return val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code has some tweaked printouts just to see exactly what is happening. I used a multiprocessing.Queue to store and share outputs across the processes and back into my main thread to be handled. I think this solves the python portion of my problem but there's still some issues in the code I'm working on. The only other thing I can say is that the equivalent to `func_to_run` involves sending a command over ssh and grabbing any err along with the output. For some reason, this works perfectly fine for a command that has a low execution time, but not well for a command that has a much larger execution time/output. I tried simulating this with the drastically different work values in my code here but haven't been able to reproduce similar results.

EDIT 3
Library code I'm using (again not mine) uses `Popen.wait()` for the ssh commands and I just read this:

> `Popen.wait()`
>   Wait for child process to terminate. Set and return returncode attribute.
>
> Warning This will deadlock when using stdout=PIPE and/or stderr=PIPE and the >child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for >the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

I adjusted the code to not buffer and just print as it is received and everything works.

Comment: You have multiple problems here.  First off: `output.append()` probably does not do what you want it to when you use `multiprocessing` module.  Secondly, the problem you report is as described: you cannot call `.join()` on a `Process` that is not owned by the currently executing `Process`.  You confess that your example is synthetic, so it's difficult to tell where the problem is.  Are you sure you're assigning the result of `Process()` to a short-lived local var like in this example?  Or are you instead using a global or instance variable (`self.process_one`, e.g.)?

Comment: For the first problem - you're right. It works when I've used threads but probably because of the shared memory space. The variables for the processes are local. Are these processes not owned by the calling process? I'm only joining processes in the functions in which they are created so I would assume that the ownership is ok unless there's some scheduling issue.

Comment: Ah!  I see it now, you're calling `join` in an `atexit` handler, but only as `multiprocessing` is trying to clean up after itself.  I will speculate that this is the result of passing a `Process` instance to another process.  If that's the case, it is IMO a subtle bug in CPython.  `Process` should refuse to be `pickle`'d and give you an exception when you try to pass it.  I know it's not easy to create a minimal reproducer but I think you'll find that it's worth your time.  It will help you and us to identify the key element of the bug.

Comment: Hi @BrianCain - I updated the question itself with a reproducer and some more thoughts. Sorry for omitting the part with `os.fork()` before. I knew it was important I just didn't think it would make the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can change the old code to not use `os.fork()` but I'd also like to know why this caused this problem and if there's a workable solution.

The key to understanding the problem is knowing exactly what `fork()` does.  CPython docs state "Fork a child process." but this presumes you understand the C library call `fork()`.

Here's what glibc's manpage says about it:

> `fork()` creates a new process by duplicating the calling process.  The new process, referred to as the child, is an exact duplicate of the calling process, referred to as the parent, except for the following points: ...

It's basically as if you took your program and made a copy of its program state (heap, stack, instruction pointer, etc) with small differences and let it execute independent of the original.  When this child process exits naturally, it will use `exit()` and that will trigger `atexit()` handlers registered by the `multiprocessing` module.

What can you do to avoid it?

- omit `os.fork()`: use `multiprocessing` instead, like you are exploring now
- probably effective: `import multiprocessing` after executing `fork()`, only in the child or parent as necessary.
- use [`_exit()`](http://Note%20The%20standard%20way%20to%20exit%20is%20sys.exit(n).%20_exit()%20should%20normally%20only%20be%20used%20in%20the%20child%20process%20after%20a%20fork().) in the child (CPython docs state, "Note The standard way to exit is sys.exit(n). _exit() should normally only be used in the child process after a fork().")

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer. Thanks a lot for all your help! I edited the question one last time with a few more notes and the implementation I had started for your first suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent solution from Cain, if you're facing the same situation as I was, where you can't control how the subprocesses are created, you can try to unregister the atexit function **in your subprocesses** to get rid of these messages:

```py
import atexit
from multiprocessing.util import _exit_function

atexit.unregister(_exit_function)
```

ATTENTION: **This may lead to leakage.** For instance, if your subprocesses have their own children, they won't be cleared. So clearify your situation and test thoroughly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are threading it one time too many. I would not thread it from `run_in_parallel`, but simply calling `run_server_client` with the proper arguments, because they will thread inside.

Comment: But won't that block until finished? I need both `run_server_client` and `do_work` to be running at the same time which is why I create a separate process here.